# Webpack - Sass loader not compiling Sass

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sass

I'm trying to introduce [Sass-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader) to an existing project so as to be able to use Sass in my React components. I've set this up successfully before in my own boiler plates and had no issues but for some reason with the current configuration it doesn't seem to play. It doesn't give any errors but rather doesn't do anything with my .scss file i'm trying to import.

I can see that there is some loaders in the `cssLoaders` config for Webpack which could be the culprit but I am only targeting .scss/ .sass files with the rule

```
test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/
```

so I wouldn't have thought this would affect it at all.

I have webpack setup with a common file and one for development. Here are both those files:

**webpack.common.js**

```
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ErrorOverlayPlugin = require('error-overlay-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
require('babel-polyfill');

const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js']
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    path: path.resolve('./dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: ['node_modules'],
        use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192,
              outputPath: 'images/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|otf)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'fonts/'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ErrorOverlayPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: 'index.html'
    }),
    new Dotenv(),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'])
  ]
};
```

And here is **webpack.dev.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ProgressBarPlugin = require('progress-bar-webpack-plugin');
const CircularDependencyPlugin = require('circular-dependency-plugin');

const paths = require('../paths');

module.exports = require('./webpack.config.base')({
  bail: false,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  stats: 'errors-only',
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  entry: {
    main: [
      require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
      paths.appPolyfillsJs,
      require.resolve('react-error-overlay'),
      paths.appIndexJs
    ]
  },
  output: {
    pathinfo: true,
    filename: 'static/js/[name].js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath)
  },

  // Load the CSS in a style tag in development
  cssLoaders: [
    {
      loader: require.resolve('style-loader'),
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      }
    },
    {
      loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
      options: {
        modules: false,
        sourceMap: true,
        importLoaders: 1
      }
    },
    {
      loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
      options: { sourceMap: true }
    }
  ],
  babelQuery: {
    cacheDirectory: true
  },
  plugins: [].concat([
    new ProgressBarPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new CircularDependencyPlugin({
      exclude: /a\.js|node_modules/, 
      failOnError: true 
    })
  ])
});
```

The part that I have added to the configuration is in webpack.common:

```
      {
        test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
```

I then just import it in the module like so:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import './test.scss';
...
```

Can anyone spot why the configuration is wrong?

Comment: try replacing test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/ with /\.scss$/

Comment: Thanks for your help but that hasn't fixed it i'm afraid

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> The sass-loader requires [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) and webpack as [peerDependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies).

Make sure [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) is installed and edit the loader `webpack.dev.js` like so:

```
{
    loader: "sass-loader",
    options: {
        includePaths: ["absolute/path/a", "absolute/path/b"]
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have `node-sass` installed as a dependency?

Comment: Yes I have node-sass installed as a dep. I added your suggested line to the cssLoaders config array but i'm now getting an error from one of my normal .css files so it looks like sass-loader is trying to parse this...

Comment: So that fixed it. Try adding `excludePath: ["path-to-css", "node_modules"]`

Comment: The issue is that there is no specific path to the css as the css files are included in whichever components folder. So there is not rule I could apply here. I would need it to identify if it is css or scss first then apply the relevant loader if that makes sense

Comment: You can alter the regex and split the scss part. Instead of `test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/` use `test: /\.css$` and `test: /\.scss$`. The sass loader should be applied only for .scss files

Comment: Ok, but how exactly would this be applied? Within the cssLoaders config?

Comment: In the common config change the test to /\.css$ (you don't need sass loader in common). In dev config make one rule for .css and one for .scss. The rule for css should not include sass-loader, only the rule for .scss.

Comment: {
      loader: require.resolve('sass-loader'),
      options: {
      }
    },
* Before postcss-loader

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177117/discussion-between-red-house-87-and-shmotam).

Comment: It's not immediately clear where to include the edit to `webpack.dev.js` ... the complete layout can be found here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#object

Comment: I got this 
>  Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema. - options has an unknown property 'includePaths'